# Populate Cell at the End of the Month

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a script where every end of a month, the cell under the specific Year and Month would be populated by percentage. Basically recording percentage every end of month.

Here is my Excel Table
[image: Here is the table]

Let's say its the End of July 2023 today, I want the percentage today to be recorded in the cell under JUL and 2023.

I've tried doing it just via Excel formulas but met with the comclusion that its impossible since we cant really reference to the percentage directly since its everchanging so the cells will keep updating, therefore defeating the purpose of recording every month.

I've figured Excel vba scripting is the way but I'm kinda new to Excel vba scripting so I dont know what I'm doing. Can you help me create a script for it?

Comment: Is the header (first row) formatted as `String` or as `Date` ("mmm")? Were from the percentage you are talking about can be taken?

Comment: Header is String right now. Percentage is from another sheet named Dashboard, I get it using formula like this =Dashboard!$L$13/(Dashboard!$L$4+Dashboard!$L$8)

Comment: OK, by this logic assimilation, supposing that years in column A:A are `General` (numeric, 
 not `Date`) formatted, would it be correct?

Comment: Yes, Years in column A:A is General Formatted

Comment: Please, test the function I supplied and send some feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, use the next function:

```
Function lastCurMonth(w As Worksheet, Optional iRow As Long = 1, Optional iCol As Long = 1) As Range
   Dim mtch, mtchY

   mtch = Application.match(CStr(Format(Date, "mmm")), w.rows(iRow), True) 'match the month column 
   mtchY = Application.match(CLng(Format(Date, "yyyy")), w.Columns(iCol), True) 'match the year row
   
   If Not IsError(mtch) And Not IsError(mtchY) Then
        Set lastCurMonth = w.cells(mtchY, mtch)
   End If
End Function
```

It can be tested/used in the next way:

```
Sub testLastCurMonth()
      Dim w As Worksheet, percentRng As Range
      
      Set w = ActiveSheet
      Set percentRng = lastCurMonth(w) 'if months header and year column are different (than 1), use their numbers, too...
      
      Debug.Print percentRng.address: Stop 'press F5 to continue, if the returned address is correct
      percentRng.Formula = "=Dashboard!$L$13/(Dashboard!$L$4+Dashboard!$L$8)"
End Sub
```

The function is simple, please ask for clarifications if something not clear enough...

Comment: Shouldn't the percentage be given the value of the percentage rather than the formula? I thought that was the issue of OP but maybe I'm mistaken..

Comment: @Notus_Panda He clarifies this aspect in his comment saying "using formula like this =Dashboard!$L$13/(Dashboard!$L$4+Dashboard!$L$8)", I think. The formula can be evaluated if he needs only the result. Maybe, it can be changed in `Dashboard` sheet during the day and he needs to have the most updated value. Or maybe not... He should clarify this aspect, if my understanding was not the correct one, I think.

Comment: He accepted your answer so I suppose your understanding was correct. Just find it odd that he needed the cells not to automatically update since that would ruin the purpose of his sheet `so the cells will keep updating, therefore defeating the purpose of recording every month.` but then is ok with it staying a formula. @Veerand can you maybe elaborate?

Comment: Ahh I think @Notus_Panda is right, The value should be the one to be in the cell instead of the formula. Is there a way we can do this? Sorry I thought it was good at first look thats why I accepted it right away.

Comment: So maybe we can like put the value of "=Dashboard!$L$13/(Dashboard!$L$4+Dashboard!$L$8" in a variable, for example var Percentage = 0.1% then this variable would be the one we put in the cell. Is something like that possible?

Comment: Okay, I solved it now, I put "=Dashboard!$L$13/(Dashboard!$L$4+Dashboard!$L$8" in cell "Q2" and made some changes in code. Basically I put Q2's value in a Variant variable and that variable is the one I put in the cell. Still gonna accept your answer tho, since it helped me tremendously. Thank you.

Comment: @Veerand Sorry, I was busy... You can simple change the line `percentRng.Formula = "=Dashboard!$L$13/(Dashboard!$L$4+Dashboard!$L$8)"` in `percentRng.Value= Application.Evaluate("=Dashboard!$L$13/(Dashboard!$L$4+Dashboard!$L$8)")`, as I suggested in one of my above comments.